# Can I Write C# in a Functional Way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, f#

I am working on a project with a few other developers.  We are ready to start building the component that handles the business logic.  We are all skilled in C#.  Functional programming for business logic and F# has been brought up by the client multiple times.  I am failing to connect the dots.  I understand using functional concepts like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GpXsQ-NIKXY).  My question is: Is functional programming simply a paradigm shift, or should we actually start using another language like F#?

Comment: This book is a good introduction to functional programming using both C# and F#: http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-Functional-Programming-Tomas-Petricek/dp/1933988924/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8

Comment: @MarkPattison Thanks marks!

Comment: It's worth reading [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/04/13/less-is-more-language-features/) and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/04/15/c-will-eventually-get-all-f-features-right/) post to help you consider using F# instead of C#.

Comment: Functional(-ish) programming in C# is possible, but tedious, as C# lacks important features like expression-basedness and currying/partial application. As for the "paradigm shift", in case you are already applying the SOLID principles in C#, it isn't even all that big (see [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional/)).

Comment: These blog posts might also be useful: https://dev.to/naveen/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-c
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/refactoring-into-pure-functions
and http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1384/functional-programming-fsharp-for-csharp-developers